# Shop/Ordering system in swift

Tags: swift

I am making a clicker game/app in swift and I am having a system where you type in a number for the ammount of "units" you want to buy and each unit costs 50 but my problem is that it goes into negative numbers somehow even though it appears that I have a system to block that out then I realized that someone could just buy infinite amounts of the item and just keep going negative heres my code

```
var intNumber : Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var podsPerClickOrder: UITextField!
@IBAction func orderButton(_ sender: Any) {

    var ppcOrder = Int(podsPerClickOrder.text!)!

    podsPerClickOrder.text = ""

    if tidePods >= ppcOrder*5
    {
        tidePods -= ppcOrder*50
        podsPerClick += ppcOrder
        tidePodScore.text = "\(tidePods)"
        ppcOrder = 0
    }
```

it uses a text field and an order button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant `if tidePods >= ppcOrder*50` instead of `if tidePods >= ppcOrder*5`.

Comment: thanks I'm kinda dumb I guess I needed a fresh pair of eyes to look at it

Comment: Glad to oblige ;-)